# why acl(acl(X))=acl(X)

Tags: logic, model-theory

Assume that $c$ is algebraic over $b_1, \ldots, b_n$. (Those $b_i$ are algebraic over $X$). Then there are functions $\varphi (c, b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ and $\chi_i(b_i)$.

$$\exists y_1, \ldots, \exists y_n : \chi_1(y_1) \wedge \ldots \wedge \chi_n(y_n) \wedge \varphi(x, y_1, \ldots, y_n)$$

$c$ realizes this formula, but why is this formula bounded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that acl(acl(A))=acl(A), in model theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18501/prove-that-aclacla-acla-in-model-theory) (in particular the accepted answer there explains how to change your formula to be bounded)

Comment: Yes.Thank you.i can change it.